# TapGestureRecognizer not working inside ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms page displaying a list of items using MVVM pattern.

I can not get the Command property of the TapGestureRecognizer object of the list items working. It does not even fire, no matter what I try.
This command property should reference a single ICommand property on the VM for all the listview elements. The CommandParameter property should select between the elements based on their Id.

The Tapped event seems to be working. I am not sure whether my databinding of the Command property to the VM is faulty or Xamarin.Forms has a bug here.

I have tried different settings for the data binding of TapGestureRecognizer's Command property to my ViewModel and I have also played with the InputTransparent properties on the nested View-elements. No change here: Command does not fire

View XAML header:

```
<ContentPage ...
             x:Class="Ch9.MainPage2"
             x:Name="page"
             >
```

View has a ViewModel property which is the viewmodel:

```
public partial class MainPage2 : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage2ViewModel ViewModel
    {
       get => BindingContext as MainPage2ViewModel;
       set => BindingContext = value;
    }

        public MainPage2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new MainPage2ViewModel(
            ...injecting components...
             );
        }
}
```

the viewmodel has an ItemTappedCommand property:

```
public ICommand ItemTappedCommand { get; private set; }
...
ItemTappedCommand = new Command<int>(async id => await OnItemTappedCommand(id));
```

Inside the page I have a stacklayout as content-root and inside the stacklayout there is a listview. To keep the code small, I have omitted what I could, what I think is not relevant

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                        
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                      <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            BindingContext="{x:Reference page}"                                        
                            Command="{Binding Path=ViewModel.ItemTappedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                <Image InputTransparent="True">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding ImgSmSrc}"
                                                    CacheValidity="0"
                                                    CachingEnabled="False"                                                    
                                                    />
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                               <StackLayout InputTransparent="True">
                              some content...
                              </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Use the ItemSelected or ItemTapped event instead of GestureRecognizer.

Comment: I would like to use MVVM pattern without code behind if and wherever possible. Currently I am refactoring from code behind (where I used ItemTapped event) to MVVM where I would like to use Commands

Comment: Where do you actually set the ViewModel as the BindingContext of your View? Your have a getter setter in your code behind but I don't see the assignment of the ViewModel

Comment: Hi Mouse! I set it in the page's constructor. I have updated the code listing accordingly. i have omitted before because I didnt want to pollute the code with noise.

Comment: Does any other binding work on this page?

Comment: All other bindings work. The VM also implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: You say you've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` but nowhere in the `set` of your `ViewModel` property do you broadcast your change. Add `OnPropertyChanged("ViewModel");` to the set of the property, that should notify the `Binding` of the new value.

Answer (score 2):

You've changed your `TapGestureRecognizer`'s `BindingContext` to your current content page but it could not notice the customized defined property `ViewModel`, you can only consume the `ContentPage`'s property.

So `{Binding Path=ViewModel.ItemTappedCommand}` this binding will fail.

I recommend you to adjust your binding like:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path= BindingContext.ItemTappedCommand, Source={x:Reference listView}}" 
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"  
                                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <!--onther stuff-->
                    <!--...-->

                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The `listView`'s binding context is your view model which has been set using code behind. At last you could consume the `ItemTappedCommand` there.

Moreover, as you want to access the Id, I only changed the `Command`'s `Source` instead of the whole gesture's binding context. Or you won't retrieve that because it belongs to the element of `SearchResults` not view model itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response Lu, I have moved forward with a workaround (using event and calling the VM command object-s Execute method from the code behind-event handler)

In a couple of days I will try your solution and report back!

Comment: @J4ni You could try this. I think MVVM should not communicate with the event.